# Having user1's home direcrory on internal hdd and user2' home direcrory on external hdd?

Tags: home-directory, external-hdd

Does anybody know if it is possible to have the home folder of one user, for example; /home/user1 on internal hdd and when i log in with user2 the /home/user2 on external hdd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user's `HOME` directory is set upon user login, from the 6th colon separated field in the user's `/etc/passwd` entry. For example, MY `/etc/passwd` file contains these users:

```
walt2:x:1001:1000:Walt2 Sullivan,,,:/home/walt2:/bin/bash
walt:x:1000:1000:Walt Sullivan,,,:/home/walt:/bin/bash
```

User `walt2`'s `HOME` directory is `/home/walt2`, and `walt`'s `HOME` directory is `/home/walt`. They could be anywhere that is mounted at the beginning of the user's login.

Read `man 5 passwd` and `man vipw` (always use `vipw` to edit the passwd - it can use any `EDITOR`, not only `vi`).

Comment: Not anywhere ;) Must be POSIX compliant.

Comment: @Rinzwind Do you have a reference to where POSIX specifies HOME directory restrictions?

Comment: It does not but it is implied. Do you know any other system that allows for the usage of permissions? Windows filesystems do not. /home needs them: large parts of the contents is owned by root. And most of the remainder by the user. Some by system users. NTFS only allowed mounting for 1 user and 1 group.

Answer (score 0):

EACH user has a file `~.config/users-dirs.dirs` in their home where you can set what your home is by editing the file (take note of the comments in the file). You can also each have your own "locale" setting:

```
rinzwind@schijfwereld:~$ more .config/user-dirs.dirs 
# This file is written by xdg-user-dirs-update
# If you want to change or add directories, just edit the line you're
# interested in. All local changes will be retained on the next run
# Format is XDG_xxx_DIR="$HOME/yyy", where yyy is a shell-escaped
# homedir-relative path, or XDG_xxx_DIR="/yyy", where /yyy is an
# absolute path. No other format is supported.
# 
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="/discworld/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="/discworld/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="/discworld/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="/discworld/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="/discworld/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="/discworld/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="/discworld/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="/discworld/Videos"
```

and

```
rinzwind@schijfwereld:~$ more .config/user-dirs.locale 
en_US
```

This is the original that uses $HOME (ie. /home/$USER/):

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

---

There is also a command line method:

```
xdg-user-dirs-update --set DOWNLOAD "directory"
```

where directory needs to fit the comments in the first code block in this answer.

Do it like this and you can even use NTFS on the external location. You would still have a /home/$USER/ directory but all the software will be using your external location. "home" is still /home/$USER/ since all settings are still there.

Comment: Thank you very much, appreciate! I this will be my solution if there is no possibility to move the whole user2 account inclusive config and setting files to an external drive. Since i modified /etc/fstab, mkdir /mnt/user2 mounted the external hdd on /mnt/user2, moved the home directory to /mnt/user2 with the usermod command, everything worked fine. The problem ist that the external hdd has to be mounted even if i want to log in with the local user1 account. With the removed exthdd boot will fail

Comment: Just put users settings and configs on the normal disk in /home/ and use the 2nd disk as a data disk. That's is safer and makes it easier to create backups (you backup the external disk). Plus you do not run into trouble when someone takes that disk out removing your home ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the rapid answers.

After thinking about for a while i think [Rinzwind](https://askubuntu.com/users/15811/rinzwind)'s solution is the cleanest so far.

I found a messy way to put the whole user2 profile on an external hdd and it works fine but it's messing with firejail on a few programs and i bet there are a few more issues coming out later .
Without drive plugged in it's booting normal, login on user1 works well, the login on user2 will be skipped and returns to the login screen since the drive will be plugged in.

If someone is interested to mess around with:

1. I made a directory /mnt/exthome
2. mounted the ext4 formatted external hdd and
3. added the new user2 with the home directory /mnt/exthome/user2.
4. and modified the /etc/fsab with option flag `nofail`

> ```
> mkdir /mnt/exthome
>
> mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/exthome
>
> adduser user --home /mnt/exthome/user2
> ```

got the UUID of the external drive with `blkid` and added the line in /etc/fstab

```
UUID=************** /mnt/xhome/   ext4  defaults,nofail    0     2
```